# Is it possible to use Puppeteer with form-data (multipart/form-data)?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to run POST multipart/form-data as below

```
      var FormData = require('form-data');
      cookies = await page.cookies()

      var form = new FormData();
      form.append('sendId', sendID);
      form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filePath));

      await page.setRequestInterception(true);

      page.once("request", interceptedRequest => {
        interceptedRequest.continue({
          method: "POST",
          postData: form,
          headers: {
            ...interceptedRequest.headers(),
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            'cookie' : cookies,
            'x-xsrf-token' : token['token'],
          }
        });

      });
```

But, It doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Please elaborate

Comment: Look like it didn't receive the file